# Exact Online import GLTransactions with automatic reconciliation

Tags: accounting, exact-online, invantive-query-tool, twinfield, xml-auditfile-financial

I am using our query tool to generate XML files for the topic `GLTransactions` of the XML API of Exact Online. The input for these files are XML Audit Files coming from Twinfield (XAF 3.1 format).

Since Exact Online has a mixed ledger and lots of constraints, it is not possible to directly load the bank entries. Instead, the bank transactions are posted into a separate General Ledger account of Exact Online with a separate journal as a first step when loading the XML Audit Files from Twinfield.

In the next step, the contents in Exact Online of the reserved General Ledger account are posted in the banking journal. Exact Online itself generates the other half as associated transaction lines for the banking general ledger.

The query used to generate the bank entries is:

```
create or replace table bank@inmemorystorage
as
select case 
       when substr(tle.description, 1, instr(tle.description, '/') - 1) = 'BNK'
       then '20'
       when substr(tle.description, 1, instr(tle.description, '/') - 1) = 'BNK2'
       then '21'
       else '??'
       end
       txn_journalcode
,      txn.financialyear txn_financialyear
,      txn.financialperiod txn_financialperiod
,      txn.entrynumber txn_entrynumber
,      txn.date txn_date
,      tle.date tle_date
,      tle.linenumber tle_linenumber
,      substr(tle.description, instr(tle.description, '/') + 1, instr(tle.description, ':') - instr(tle.description, '/') - 1) tle_glaccountcode_target
,      substr(tle.description, instr(tle.description, ':') + 2) tle_description
,      trim(tle.accountcode) tle_accountcode
,      tle.glaccountcode glaccountcode_source
,      tle.amountdc tle_amountdc
,      tle.vatcode tle_vatcode
,      tle.yourref tle_yourref
from   exactonlinerest..transactionlines tle
join   exactonlinerest..transactions txn
on     tle.entryid = txn.entryid
where  tle.glaccountcode like '290%'
and    substr(tle.description, instr(tle.description, '/') + 1, instr(tle.description, ':') - instr(tle.description, '/') - 1) not like '11%' /* Not a bank account. */
order 
by     tle.entrynumber
,      tle.linenumber

select 'GLTransactions\99-Interim-empty.xml' 
       filename
,      stg.fileprefix 
       || chr(13)
       || '<GLTransactions>' 
       || xml 
       || chr(13)
       || '</GLTransactions>'
       || stg.filepostfix
       filecontents
from   ( select listagg
                ( chr(13)
                  || '<GLTransaction entry="'
                  || txn_entrynumber
                  || '">'
                  || chr(13)
                  || '<Journal code="'
                  || txn_journalcode
                  || '" />'
                  || chr(13)
                  || '<Date>'
                  || substr(xmlencode(txn_date), 1, 10)
                  || '</Date>'
                  || chr(13)
                  || xml
                  || chr(13)
                  || '</GLTransaction>'
                  , ''
                  ) xml
          from    ( select txn_date
                    ,      txn_journalcode
                    ,      txn_financialyear
                    ,      txn_financialperiod
                    ,      txn_entrynumber
                    ,      listagg
                           ( chr(13)
                             || '<GLTransactionLine type="40" linetype="0" line="'
                             || tle_linenumber 
                             || '" offsetline="1" status="20">'
                             || chr(13)
                             || '<Date>'
                             || substr(xmlencode(tle_date), 1, 10)
                             || '</Date>'
                             || chr(13)
                             || '<FinYear number="'
                             || txn_financialyear
                             || '" />'
                             || chr(13)
                             || '<FinPeriod number="'
                             || txn_financialperiod
                             || '" />'
                             || chr(13)
                             || '<GLAccount code="'
                             || case
                                when tle_glaccountcode_target = '1560' 
                                then '2902' /* Separate interim GL account, Twinfield does not provide separated. */
                                else xmlencode(tle_glaccountcode_target)
                                end
                             || '" />'
                             || case 
                                when tle_description is not null 
                                then chr(13)
                                     || '<Description>'
                                     || xmlencode(tle_description)
                                     || '</Description>'
                                     end
                             || case
                                when tle_accountcode is not null
                                then chr(13)
                                     || '<Account code="'
                                     || xmlencode(tle_accountcode)
                                     || '" />'
                                end
                             || chr(13)
                             || '<Amount>'
                             || '<Currency code="EUR" />'
                             || '<Value>'
                             || -1 * tle_amountdc
                             || '</Value>'
                             || case 
                                when tle_glaccountcode_target like '4%'
                                then '<VAT code="GB" />' /* GB = No VAT. */
                                else ''
                                end
                             || '</Amount>'
                             || chr(13)
                             || '</GLTransactionLine>'
                             , ''
                           )
                           xml
                    from   bank@inmemorystorage
                    group 
                    by     txn_date
                    ,      txn_journalcode
                    ,      txn_financialyear
                    ,      txn_financialperiod
                    ,      txn_entrynumber
                    )
       )
join   settings@inmemorystorage stg
on     1=1
```

In the column `tle_yourref` in `bank@inmemorystorage` there is a comma-separated list of associated sales/purchase invoices.

When manually entering the General Ledger transaction on the bank journal, the contents of your ref are populated by the reconciliation window. However, when I export the XML file from Exact Online with transactions, the your ref is missing.

At this moment I seem uncapable to automatically reconcile through an XML or REST API of Exact Online these transactions in the bank journal.

As a workaround you can select each individual account in Reconciliation window (they practically all amount to EUR 0) and then choose Automatic reconciliation. But there are too many accounts to do it with each conversion from Twinfield to Exact Online.

Is there an alternative way to associate invoices with the bank transactions through an API (REST or XML) of Exact Online?

Comment: With <References><YourRef>xxx</YourRef></References> you can import the reference, but still no automatic reconciliation possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a 1 on 1 relation between the invoice and the payment (so only 1 invoice and 1 payment) you can use `<References><InvoiceNumber>put invoice entrynumber here</InvoiceNumber></References>` in the bank entry to have it automatically reconciled.

Another possibility is to create an XML file with the topic `MatchSets` (see documentation) to have it matched afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. The automatic reconciliation using matching `<InvoiceNumber>` or `<YourRef>` does not seem to succeed. Using MatchSets it seems possible; just a lot of data :-)

Comment: Can you Provide me link for this MatchSets Documentation, I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: It can be found in the XSD schema, it is not available in the REST API. Use XMLDownload.aspx?Topic=MatchSets&_Division_={division} to get an example.

Comment: <eExact>
    <MatchSets>
        <MatchSet>
            <GLAccount code="123" /><Account code="123"/>
            <MatchLines>
                <MatchLine finyear="2012" finperiod="1" journal="990" entry="26" amountdc="-23595.03" />
                <MatchLine finyear="2012" finperiod="1" journal="990" entry="50" amountdc="-20142.14" />
                <MatchLine finyear="2012" finperiod="2" journal="990" entry="51" amountdc="20142.14" />
                <MatchLine finyear="2012" finperiod="2" journal="990" entry="51" amountdc="23595.03" />
            </MatchLines>
        </MatchSet>

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also say:

```
<References><EntryNumber>10000012</EntryNumber><InvoiceNumber>FAC0001</InvoiceNumber></References>
```

This always works when the relation is 1=1.
If you specify only the invoice number the matching often fails silently.

Comment: Of course, this EntryNumber if the reference to the invoice entry number of Exact Online.